# Error: "Warning: Cannot find word list" - Is this a user or package error?

Tags: spell-checking

I'm a longtime user of vim on Archlinux. I've been away from this system for a few months, so I can't be sure when this started (but I've made updates during this time, too).

Every time I open the app, I get an error about the spelling file.

```
$ vim
Warning: Cannot find word list "en.utf-8.spl" or "en.ascii.spl"
Warning: Cannot find word list "en.utf-8.spl" or "en.ascii.spl"
Warning: Cannot find word list "en.utf-8.spl" or "en.ascii.spl"
Press ENTER or type command to continue

$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 15 2016 10:11:05)
Included patches: 1-5
Compiled by Arch Linux

$ sudo pacman -Ss vim | grep installed
extra/vim 8.0.0005-1 [installed]
extra/vim-runtime 8.0.0005-1 [installed]
community/ranger 1.7.2-1 [installed]
```

I reinstalled the app, but the problem persists. 
The problem is for all users.

Comment: This doesn't come from the package. It seems that you have `set spell` enabled but didn't downloaded the spell files. You can have a look at [this blog post](http://abhipandey.com/2015/10/vim-cannot-find-word-list/) and [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5651/1841). I think the solution is to download the spell files and put them in `~/.vim/spell`. Note that usually vim offers to download the files automatically so I think the question I linked before might help you.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same problem and my `vimrc` was containing this lines. It disables the default, built-in `netrw` plugin. I don't know why but somehow spell files couldn't be downloaded if netrw disabled.

```
let g:loaded_netrwPlugin = 1 " Disables netrw.
```

Solution was *at least for me* to delete this line to enable netrw again.

Comment: Disabling netrw is suggested by some plugins, for example [nvim-tree](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua). I disabled the plugin and nvim offered to download the spell files!