# Generate new spell file from .aff & .dic

Tags: spell-checking, spelling

Im trying to generate a new spell lang file for Romanian, but using format before 1993 when  new orthographic rules was implemented. To summarize before 1993 we wrote for eg: `cînd` and now we write `când`

I downloaded [this extension](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/classic-romanian-dictionary-pack-spell-checker-hyphenation-thesaurus), I extracted it and this is the content:

```
 ./
├── COPYING.GPL
├── COPYING.LGPL
├── COPYING.MPL
├── description.xml
├── Dictionaries.xcu
├── file.txt
├── hyph_ro_RO.dic
├── manifest.xml
├── META-INF/
│  └── manifest.xml
├── README_EN.txt
├── README_RO.txt
├── ro_RO.aff
└── ro_RO.dic
```

I opened vim and execute: `:mkspell ~/.vim/spell/ro ~/Downloads/dict-ro-classic.1.7/ro_RO.aff`. Is generating a file `ro.utf-8.spl` but has only 44kb in contrast with 1.1MB that is downloading from the official vim ftp.

What I am doing wrong? I read [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5651/how-can-i-make-vim-download-spell-files) and [the help docs](https://vimhelp.org/spell.txt.html?#aff-dic-format), but I didn't succeded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
>       The input can be the Myspell format files {inname}.aff
>       and {inname}.dic.  If {inname}.aff does not exist then
>       {inname} is used as the file name of a plain word
>       list.
> ```

Omit `aff` extension from command line and it should succeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, it is not working. Here is what I get: https://pastebin.com/L8gJH3X2

Comment: @Mafsi I checked and it worked. Should be some kind of local problem on your machine (small output file = .dic was not found/processed).

Comment: I had to press more on that long list of errors to see what happened. It was generated but is full of errors, see here the end https://pastebin.com/jFSWkyAJ.  Now in `.vimrc` I have `set spell` and `set spelllang=ro` and when I open the vim I get: `Error detected while processing /home/mafsi/.vimrc[345]../home/mafsi/.vim/spell/ro.utf-8.spl: E783: duplicate char in MAP entry Press ENTER or type command to continue`. What could be my local machine problem?

Comment: I accepted your answer because it is the right one. I don't know why I have these errors. If you can generate the file without errors and care to upload somewhere for me to have it, I will appreciate it. I found other .aff & .dic files and I managed to generate a spell file without errors, but on those file were other problems: cedilla instead of commabellow. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Mafsi 1) Do `:set spelllang=ro` but **not** `:set spell` in your vimrc. Only `set spell` manually for files in Romanian that you want to spell check; it may complain upon running spell check for the first time but it still works; 2) It complains on lines 1832-33 and 1837 in ro_RO.aff; you can check these lines and, maybe, comment them out; then you can rebuild spl and there'll be no errors anymore but I have no idea what will be broken as a result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I still think that, as you said there is a problem with my machine because when I compile the modern spell file I still get the errors. But when I let vim   do this automatically form official ftp everything is ok.